# Image Processing Softwares

Tags: image-processing

I need to process the text inside the image. The image is of the meter reading the data.
I tried with [NewOcr](http://www.newocr.com)  and few other free online image processing software, but they didnt read the data correctly.

Which are the best image processing softwares(both freeware and shareware) that can read meter data accurately?

PS: I need to get the exact reading from the image processed. So, I cannot afford to handle inappropriate data.

The images which will be processed can be found on [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37280036@N04/) link.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract perhaps? http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ im not sure you will be able to avoid inappropriate data, the OCR will make a mistake eventually and some will slip through.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you tu use  [matlab ocr](http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html)  for text recognition. In general for image processing i sugges you [image processing MATLAB toolbox](http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/getting-started-with-image-processing-toolbox.html)